# Wifi keeps disconnecting and reconnecting all the time

Tags: networking, 20.04, 20.10, atheros, wpa-supplicant

I have a problem with WIFI not being stable, and disconnecting -> reconnecting, all the time (I have PC next to the router). It happens like every 10 seconds average (one time it happened twice in a row, and another time I got 30 seconds without disconnect).

My specs: 
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (On 20.10 same issue) 
Wifi card: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter (ath9k) 
Motherboard: MSI X470 Gaming Plus Max 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 
wpasupplicant: 2:2.9-1ubuntu4.1

I've tried so far disabling IPV6, disabling powersave mode, creating ath9k.conf and adding parameters, setting manually BSSID and MAC adress, installing backport-iwlwifi-dkms, installing firmware-ath9k-htc, using 2,4G network, updating bios, checking if it's not a hardware problem.

My wifi card worked perfectly on Arch Linux when I tried it and I know they're using some backports, so maybe installing that backports would solve the issue? (I don't know what backports they're using)

This issue wasn't present on Ubuntu 18.04

[journalctl log](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/520522513/journalctl_ubuntu)
[dmesg log](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/520522521/dmesg_ubuntu)

Anyone knows what else could I try to do? Thanks in advance!

Edit: I thought it was somehow related to gnome de, but it also happens on kde (checked kde neon)

Comment: I used a WiFi dongle with an LED that did this, turned off the LED and it was fine. Other thing to look at is power saving; `modinfo $(lsmod|grep ath)` (untested, not presently at computer) for the driver module sometimes has useful info.

Comment: Hvae you tried to update your wireless driver?

Comment: How could I update my driver? Software Center shows no updates, as well as `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. My Wifi dongle doesn't have any LED. Also maybe important is that my wifi dongle is connected by PCI

Comment: Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: Still no idea how to solve it?